# What is $\ddot y(t) = a(t), $y(t) defined for $t \ge 0$, with boundary condition?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following question which I do not know how to tackle. Any hints are welcome.

Consider the second-order differential equation
$\ddot y(t) = a(t), $y(t) defined for $t \ge 0$ with the boundary condition $\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{y(t)}{t} = 1$ at $\infty$.

Show that if $a(t) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1]$ and vanishes for $t\ge 1$ is a smooth function, then the equation admits a nonnegative solution, i.e., $y(t) \ge 0$.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: What are the initial conditions? Is $y(0)\ge 0$? What about $y'(0)$? Obviously $y'(1)=1$.

Comment: I guess a way of looking at it is to think of $y(1)$ as a "shooting method parameter" and adjust it until you get a nonnegative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a solution $z$ with $z(0)=z'(0)=1$. The point $(z,z')$ in phase space starts in the first quadrant and thus will remain there, moving away from the origin. So $z'(1)$ is positive.

Now set $y=z/z'(1)$ to get $y'(1)=1$. As $y''(t)=0$ for $t>1$, this slope remains constant, $y(t)=y(1)+(t-1)$ is linear and $y(t)/t$ converges to the slope value $1$.

Comment: Strictly speaking the way you started is not guaranteed to be possible; consider as a stupid example $a \equiv 0$. In this case of course the result obviously holds (since just $y=t$ is a solution) but your proof breaks down since $z'(1)$ is zero.

Comment: What I was trying to do was to say $y=y(1) + \int_1^t y'(x) dx = y(1) + t-1 + \int_1^t \int_1^x y''(s) ds dx$ (using $y'(1)=1$), but I wasn't sure how to continue after that.

Comment: With $a=0$ everywhere, that is $y''(t)=0$, my construction gives $z(t)=1+t$, $z'(1)=1$, so that also $y(t)=1+t$ and $x(t)/t=1/t+1$ indeed converges to $1$.

Comment: No, your construction gives $z \equiv 1$ if $a \equiv 0$.

Comment: Ok, this was a stupid automatism. I wanted initial conditions, not boundary conditions.

Comment: Ah, now it makes more sense. I was also wondering about whether non-uniqueness could cause any problems with your setup, but now that issue is resolved as well. This "phase space invariance" idea is quite powerful here...

Answer (score 1):

Require $y'(1)=1$ for the BC at infinity, then write

$$y(t)=y(1) + y'(1)(t-1) + \int_1^t \int_1^x y''(s) ds dx = y(1) - 1 + t + \int_1^t \int_1^x a(s) y(s) ds dx.$$

This is now in the form of a fixed point equation. Note that the double integral is nonnegative (no matter whether $t>1$ or $t<1$) provided that $y$ is, and $y(1) - 1 + t$ is nonnegative if $y(1) \geq 1$. So by induction, the fixed point iterates starting from, say, $y=y(1)-1+t$ are all nonnegative if $y(1) \geq 1$.

These iterates converge on some neighborhood of $1$ to a nonnegative function which solves the ODE IVP.

Now you need to propagate this observation to all of $[0,\infty)$. This is doable, but there is no new insight to be gained, you just do the same procedure over again starting from a point to the left of $1$ and continue until you actually get to $0$. (To the right of $1$ there is no difficulty because the double integral will just be $0$ for $t>1$.)

Comment: Where did you get these integrals from? I am not as advanced as you.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Fundamental theorem of calculus: $y(t)=y(1)+\int_1^t y'(x) dx = y(1) + \int_1^t \left ( y'(1) + \int_1^x y''(s) ds \right ) dx$.